# Change FORM SELECT (dropdown menu) depending on other dropdown in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with two drop down menus and I want the selectable values in the second drop down menu to change depending on what is chosen with the first drop down

This is drop down one:

```
<select name="cat" id="1">
   <option>MAMMAL</option>
   <option>REPTILE</option>
   <option>BIRD</option>
</select>
```

And depending on the selection I immediately want one of these forms displayed:

```
<select name="type" id="type1">
   <option>CAT</option>
   <option>DOG</option>
</select

<select name="type" id="type1">
   <option>SNAKE</option>
   <option>LIZARD</option>
</select

<select name="type" id="type1">
   <option>HEN</option>
   <option>ROBIN</option>
</select
```

The form is for multiple entries so there's many rows with the id number increasing each time.
My jQuery so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".cat").live("click", function(event)
   {      
     cid=event.target.id;
     catchosen = event.target.value;

     switch (catchosen)
     {
        case 'MAMMAL':
        case 'REPTILE':
        case 'BIRD':
        return {}
     };
     event.preventDefault();
  });  
});
```

How do I change/replace the values in a dropdown list with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you use the selector  `$(".cat")` , you should have your first select box the class `cat` assigned. But it's always good to select using a `id` in this case. And I would suggest you to use `change` event instead of `click` event on detecting change of select option of the first select box.

You can use the `.empty()` jquery function to clear the 2nd drop down's options and then use `.append()` to add new options to it.

Something like

```
$("#type1").empty(); //clear all options
$("#type1").append('<option value="CAT">CAT</option>');
```

Comment: I forgot to add the class in my example, but thanks for the change event advice.
The empty and append works great too, thank you for your help!

Comment: or use $('select[name="cat"]')

Answer (score 1):

Give separate ids for you select. i.e, type1, type2 and type3. Change youe script like this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".cat").live("click", function(event)
   {
     catchosen = this.value;
     $("#type1, #type2, #type3").hide();
     switch (catchosen)
     {
        case 'MAMMAL':
            $("#type1").show();
            break;
        case 'REPTILE':
            $("#type2").show();
            break;
        case 'BIRD':
            $("#type3").show();
            break;
     };
  });  
});
```